# Jquery equal heights script

Tags: javascript, jquery

K so for study purposes I created my own equal height script (to equal the height of selected divs). I know several are out there but sometimes recreating something a different way, you learn out of it.

I made the script so you could use grouped classes like:

- equal
- equal1
- equal****

But for some reason none of it is working and I can't seem to figure out why.
Here is my code:

```
// Equal height for div boxes in dashboards
function equalHeight(group) {
console.log("test");
    var tallest = 0;
    var uniques = [];
    group.each(function (i) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(i, uniques)) {
            uniques.push(i);
        }
    });
    $(uniques).each(function () {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    equalHeight($("*[class^='equal']"));
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xw3dj0q/

Comment: Check http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/

Comment: provide a fiddle as well.

Comment: jsfiddle added, thanks for replying.
@Murali: thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to try this myself.

Comment: @Goowik: Have you debugged your selector? i.e: In your document ready do: `console.log($("*[class^='equal']"));` the in the console check the `length` property which is `0`, as in, zero elements have been found. Your selector is not targeting the desired elements. - `$(".equal")` is what you are looking for most likely. Ones fixed your code has more issues but the error messages are going to tell you exactly what's wrong and you can start fixing them one by one. If you have issues with any of them you can update your question :)

Comment: Sorry I overlooked this comment. I did try and debug it and as you suggested it was the selector that wasn't correct to start with. I actually need $('[class*=equal]') as Chris Spittles suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Issues

Your selector has a syntax error and can't find any matching elements. If you are using a partial class selector (as your question suggests), your selector should be:

```
$('[class*=equal]')
```

You are using `i` to test for uniqueness, but `i` is the unique index value for each loop iteration therefore every item will be unique.

```
jQuery.inArray(i, uniques)
```

Also [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/), returns a number not a boolean so if you are checking if an item is not in the array you need to use:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(i, uniques) < 0)
```

or

```
if (jQuery.inArray(i, uniques) === -1)
```

The last issue is that uniques is an array of numbers but you are trying to convert that to a jQuery obj which yields an error when jQuery tries to iterate over it:

```
$(uniques).each(function ()
```

Also you can replace the `if` statement and use `Math.max()` which will evaluate the two values passed to it and will decide which one is the higher value like this:

```
.each(function () {        
    tallest = Math.max( tallest, $(this).height() );        
})
```

Your `unique` array won't actually work, because you are checking to see if the index value is present in the array and if it isn't - you're adding it. The problem is, the index value is always unique because it increments with each iteration. You could try using a class as group selector but multiple classes will make it unique.

---

## Alternate Method 1

If you want to differentiate groups of elements you can call the same function multiple times and use a different selector like so:

```
function equalHeight(group) {   
    var tallest = 0;   
    group
        .each(function () {        
            tallest = Math.max( tallest, $(this).height() );        
        })
        .height(tallest);
}
$(function() {    
    equalHeight($('.equal1')); 
    equalHeight($('.equal2'));    
});
```

Trying to build a set of unique elements to iterate over separately isn't going to work without something unique identifying each group.

Have a look at this example:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5xw3dj0q/5/)

---

## Alternate Method 2

This method follows your example more closely but requires a mark-up change for it to work. You need a unique group identifier, in this instance I have used a class i.e `equal1` and `equal2`. The problem is because you were using multiple classes, the class names (when evaluated) were all unique.

```
function equalHeight(group) {

    var uniques = [];
    
    group.each(function (i) {
        if ($.inArray($(this).attr("class"), uniques) < 0) {            
            uniques.push($(this).attr("class"));            
        }
    });
    
    for (i=0; i<uniques.length; i++) {
        
        var tallest = 0;        
        group
            .filter("." + uniques[i])
            .each(function (i) {
                
                tallest = Math.max( tallest, $(this).height() );    
            })
            .height(tallest);
    }
}
$(function() {
    equalHeight($('[class*=equal]'));
});
```

Personally I think this is inefficient compared the first alternate method.

Here is the example:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5xw3dj0q/7/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works perfectly for all equal classes, the problem though is it will set the height of equal1 for example the same as equal2 (which should be different). Sorry I should have explained better.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're not selecting the class `equal`. The correct selector is `$(".equal")`
As your selector is not returning elements, you're calculating the height of an empty array.

When selecting the correct nodes in the DOM, your script functions properly. What I couldn't figure out was what the "uniques" array is for.

```
// Equal height for div boxes in dashboards
function equalHeight(group) {
    console.log("test");
    var tallest = 0;
    var uniques = [];

    group.each(function (i) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(i, uniques)) {
            uniques.push(i);
        }
    });

    group.each(function () {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });

    group.height(tallest);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    equalHeight($(".equal"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xw3dj0q/1/

Comment: Well the idea of my height script was that you could have several "equal" classes. each different name should have its own tallest measurement. So lets say you have 2 **equal1** classes and 3 **equal2** classes. The equal1 would have a different tallest height than the equal2.